# Reflexive Banach spaces and norms

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,|.|)$ be a reflexive Banach space, and $Y\subset X$ such that $(Y,|.|_Y)$ is a Banach space with a norm $|.|_Y$ stronger than $|.|$, i.e. there's a constant $C$ such that
$$|y|\leq C |y|_Y, \ \ \forall y\in Y$$
What can we say about $(Y,|.|_Y)$ ? is it reflexive ?

Comment: $Y=\ell_1$ sits inside $X=\ell_2$ and your inequality is satisfied with $C=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative, a counterexample was given by David Mitra:

> $Y=\ell_1$ sits inside $X=\ell_2$ and your inequality is satisfied with $C=1$.

Pushing this further, I'll show that *every* separable Banach space (and some nonseparable ones) can be realized as $Y$ inside of $X=\ell_2$. To begin with, every separable space is isometrically isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_\infty$. Let $T:\ell_\infty\to\ell_2$ be the operator defined by 
$$T(\{x_n\}) = \{x_n/n\}$$
This is an injective bounded operator. Its image can be taken as $Y$ in your setting, with the norm $\|y\|_Y = \|T^{-1}y\|_{\infty}$.

---

But if you assume in addition that $Y$ is closed in the norm of $X$, then (by the open mapping theorem) the  two-sided inequality 
$$c\|y\|_Y\le \|y\|\le C\|y\|_Y \quad \forall y\in Y$$
holds, and therefore $Y$ is reflexive (being isomorphic to a subspace of a reflexive space).